# change tab and push controller onto navigation stack programatically

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar application.  One of the tabs has a navigation stack.  I would like to change tabs programatically and then push a new controller onto the selected tabs stack.  I can change tabs fine:

```
   KidScienceAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KidScienceAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UITabBarController *tab=[appDelegate tabBarController] ;
    tab.selectedIndex=2;
```

If I just run that, it properly move to the tab with the navigation stack and shows the root view.  I'd like to then push a new controller onto that stack.  I've tried this:

```
ExperimentsNameViewController *detailViewController = [[ExperimentsNameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExperimentsNameView" bundle:nil];

FindViewController *c = [tab.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
[c.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];
```

but this doesn't push the controller.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a navigation controller at index 2, you will get a navigation controller when you do `[tab.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];` so it should be

```
[..]
UINavigationController * navigationController = [tab.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
[navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];
```